# Unity Quiz Game Score in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a quiz game in the unity from the unity live session quiz game tutorials everything is working fine except somehow the score isn't working when i Click the button it should add 10 score to the Score. Here are the tutorials : https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/intro-and-setup?playlist=17117 and the code for my Game Controller :

```
    using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class GameController : MonoBehaviour {


    public Text questionDisplayText;
    public Text scoreDisplayText;
    public Text timeRemainingDisplayText;
    public SimpleObjectPool answerButtonObjectPool;
    public Transform answerButtonParent;
    public GameObject questionDisplay;
    public GameObject roundEndDisplay;

    private DataController dataController;
    private RoundData currentRoundData;
    private QuestionData[] questionPool;

    private bool isRoundActive;
    private float timeRemaining;
    private int questionIndex;
    private int playerScore;
    private List<GameObject> answerButtonGameObjects = new List<GameObject>();

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        dataController = FindObjectOfType<DataController> ();
        currentRoundData = dataController.GetCurrentRoundData ();
        questionPool = currentRoundData.questions;
        timeRemaining = currentRoundData.timeLimitInSeconds;
        UpdateTimeRemainingDisplay();

        playerScore = 0;
        questionIndex = 0;

        ShowQuestion ();
        isRoundActive = true;

    }

    private void ShowQuestion()
    {
        RemoveAnswerButtons ();
        QuestionData questionData = questionPool [questionIndex];
        questionDisplayText.text = questionData.questionText;

        for (int i = 0; i < questionData.answers.Length; i++) 
        {
            GameObject answerButtonGameObject = answerButtonObjectPool.GetObject();
            answerButtonGameObjects.Add(answerButtonGameObject);
            answerButtonGameObject.transform.SetParent(answerButtonParent);

            AnswerButton answerButton = answerButtonGameObject.GetComponent<AnswerButton>();
            answerButton.Setup(questionData.answers[i]);
        }
    }

    private void RemoveAnswerButtons()
    {
        while (answerButtonGameObjects.Count > 0) 
        {
            answerButtonObjectPool.ReturnObject(answerButtonGameObjects[0]);
            answerButtonGameObjects.RemoveAt(0);
        }
    }

    public void AnswerButtonClicked(bool isCorrect)
    {
        if (isCorrect) 
        {
            playerScore += currentRoundData.pointsAddedForCorrectAnswer;
            scoreDisplayText.text = "Score: " + playerScore.ToString();
        }

        if (questionPool.Length > questionIndex + 1) {
            questionIndex++;
            ShowQuestion ();
        } else 
        {
            EndRound();
        }

    }

    public void EndRound()
    {
        isRoundActive = false;

        questionDisplay.SetActive (false);
        roundEndDisplay.SetActive (true);
    }

    public void ReturnToMenu()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene ("MenuScreen");
    }

    private void UpdateTimeRemainingDisplay()
    {
        timeRemainingDisplayText.text = "Time: " + Mathf.Round (timeRemaining).ToString ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        if (isRoundActive) 
        {
            timeRemaining -= Time.deltaTime;
            UpdateTimeRemainingDisplay();

            if (timeRemaining <= 0f)
            {
                EndRound();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

and my answer Button Code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class AnswerButton : MonoBehaviour {

    public Text answerText;

    private AnswerData answerData;
    private GameController GameController;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        GameController = FindObjectOfType<GameController> ();
    }

    public void Setup(AnswerData data)
    {
        answerData = data;
        answerText.text = answerData.answerText;
    }


    public void HandleClick()
    {
        GameController.AnswerButtonClicked (answerData.isCorrect);
    }
}
```

and Answer Data :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[System.Serializable]
public class AnswerData 
{
    public string answerText;
    public bool isCorrect;

}
```

Comment: Where do you call your AnswerButtonClicked method? This is button OnClick event?

Comment: What does your `AnswerButton` code look like? Place debug code in `AnswerButtonClicked()` to be sure that the button click event is being handled.

Comment: I added the Answer Button Code in the description check again.

Comment: your code looks fine, you can try adding some Debug.Log() printouts to trace what's going on

Answer (score 1):

If everything is working fine (the whole code gets executed correctly, which I presume at this point), you probably did not set the data correctly. In your Game Controller, you have the line

```
playerScore += currentRoundData.pointsAddedForCorrectAnswer;
```

in your `AnswerButtonClicked` method which should add an amount you defined to the score if the answer is correct. Since I presume that your whole code is running fine (I can't see your in-engine setup, only the code here, which looks like the one in the tutorial), this is probably the first location where to look at the error. This value is probably set in the Unity Inspector or via another script, so you may want to go check in other files or the Editor.

The next thing to check is, if the buttons are correctly linked via their event handler. This can be checked by looking at the inspector. In the tutorial series this step is done in part *Click to answer* at the end of the video.